# feed dialog shows an error occurred when I use my appid.When I use FB developers example app id it works

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have an app on facebook. Through my site, I open, using JavaScript, a popup. The querystring appearing on Facebook developers site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) which is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=458358780877780&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/
```

The popup works well and everything is ok.
When I change the app id parameter to my app id, it's not working and it displays "An error occurred...".

What is the reason for that?

Another question related, I moved to facebook feed dialog because the Facebook sharer didn't show certain images. Is it possible to make the facebook feed dialog look like the share option?

Thanks,

Comment: Is your app in sandbox mode?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specified App Domain and Site URL. Those have to point to the server where your Share Feed Dialog will be triggered from. As for testing it can point to local host.

Example:

`App Domain: localhost`

```
Site URL: http://localhost:12345/
```

Good luck!
Marta

Comment: I have configured a test app as suggested above, but I'm getting a 500 error. Any ideas?

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id={my test app id}&
display=popup&
link=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54590%2Fblog%2F2015%2F11%2Fbuilding-new-skills-with-lego%2F&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54590%2FCloseWindow.htm&
name=Building%20New%20Skills!&
description=%20blah%2C%20blah...&
picture=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54590%2Fmyimage.png&
ref=BB`